# Cannot Access Global Variables Inside citrus-context.xml

Tags: citrus-framework

Given the following `citrus-context.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:citrus="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/config"
    xmlns:citrus-http="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/http/config"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/config http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/config/citrus-config.xsd
       http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/http/config http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/http/config/citrus-http-config.xsd">

    <citrus:global-variables>
        <citrus:file
            path="classpath:endpoints.properties" />
    </citrus:global-variables>

    <citrus-http:client
        id="service_endpoint"
        request-url="${Service.Endpoint.URL}"
        request-method="GET"
        content-type="text/xml"
        charset="UTF-8"
        timeout="60000" />
</beans>
```

Instead of evaluating `${Service.Endpoint.URL}` to `http://foo.io/service` I get the following error:

```java
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${Service.Endpoint.URL}
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${Service.Endpoint.URL}
...
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${Service.Endpoint.URL}
```

Is it this because of a configuration issue, or is the current set-up not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add a Spring property placeholder configurer to your application context. The configurer is able to evaluate property expressions in Spring bean definitions. The Citrus global variables are not taken into account at design time when the Spring beans are parsed in the application context.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:endpoint.properties"/>
```

The property placeholder is using the special `context:` Spring bean namespace. So you need to declare this namespace in your configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:citrus="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/config"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
              ...">
```